# Why does my WCF service give the message 'does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion'?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a working WCF service. I now want to add some security to it to filter Ip Addresses. I have followed the example that microsoft publish in the samples to try and add a IDispatchMessageInspector that will raise a call AfterReceiveRequest and then throw an error if the ip address is not from the allowed list.

After looking at the code; they have configured it using 'wsHttpBinding', however I want to use 'webHttpBinding' or 'basicHttpBinding'. But when I set it up I get the error:

> The endpoint at 'http://upload/api/Api.svc/soap' does not have a
>   Binding with the None MessageVersion. 
>   'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is only intended for
>   use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

My configuration is:

```
<system.serviceModel>


    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <!--Set up the service-->
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SOAPRESTDemoBehavior" name="HmlApi">
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="VLSCore2.Interfaces.IHmlApi" behaviorConfiguration="SOAPRESTDemoEndpointBehavior" />
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="VLSCore2.Interfaces.IHmlApi" behaviorConfiguration="SOAPRESTDemoEndpointBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <!--Define the behaviours-->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SOAPRESTDemoBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <!---Endpoint -->
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SOAPRESTDemoEndpointBehavior">
          <ipFilter/>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="ipFilter" type="VLSCore2.Api.IpFilterBehaviourExtensionElement, VLSCore2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

So what im wondering is how I can set up my message inspector without using WebHttpBinding. Is this even possible?

I want to use SOAP 'basicHttpBinding' not wsHttpBinding (and all of the WS*) associated overheads....

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is simply happening because you have configured a single endpointBehavior for both the SOAP and REST endpoints but the SOAP endpoint can't have the webHttp behavior. You need to split these apart so that they are:

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SOAPDemoEndpointBehavior">
      <ipFilter/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="RESTDemoEndpointBehavior">
      <ipFilter/>
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

and then your endpoints should be:

```
    <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="VLSCore2.Interfaces.IHmlApi" behaviorConfiguration="RESTDemoEndpointBehavior" />
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="VLSCore2.Interfaces.IHmlApi" behaviorConfiguration="SOAPDemoEndpointBehavior" />
```

Comment: Thanks alot this was spot on. Fair to say I think its important to set up all the correct endpoints for a service now!

Comment: Man I was struggling for a couple of hours already and I arrived here to noticed that I haven't changed the binding :))) I was using basic for http request from a mobile app... thumb up +

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was because I had a 'webHttp' defined as a behaviour for a SOAP config. Only its absence resolved it..

Answer (score 0):

For 4 days, I have been up and down through MS documentation, Stack overflow and everything else. trying to get the configuration file working correctly after I started using HTTPS / SSL for requests from my service.  The setup of this configuration file is so critical.

I did not have to modify any of the code switching from HTTP to HTTPS is was all in the web.config file system.serviceModel section.

This config works for using javascript to access JSON data from the ASP.NET c# WCF.  I am so happy!

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"> 
</serviceHostingEnvironment>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors> 
    <behavior name="webBehavior"> 
        <webHttp /> 
    </behavior> 
  </endpointBehaviors> 
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>  
    <binding name="sfbSecureBinding">  
      <security mode="Transport">  
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>  
      </security>  
    </binding>  
  </webHttpBinding>  
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="buildingsWebService.Service1">
    <endpoint address="https://www.azsfb.gov/Service/Service1.svc" 
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="sfbSecureBinding" 
        contract="buildingsWebService.IService1"
        behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"> 
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://www.azsfb.gov/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>


<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

</system.serviceModel>